# Contenteditable vs input replacement

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

i'm working on an app that will have a listing of the data you've saved previously. if you have a typo, didn't enter all the data points originally, etc. you'll have the opportunity to edit the data chunk.

right now i have javascript getting the values of each element (that was created via foreach loop in php with data from the server) within a given chunk, saving it to an object and then replacing those elements (`<p>`) with textarea inputs then filling it with the data from the js object that grabbed it previously.

for one i'm having issues with escaping quotes from the dynamic content but also it feels like this may not be the most elegant solution.

in comes contenteditable.

basically: should i go that route and just make each of the elements in the data chunk contenteditable='true' on click of 'edit' button or is that too fishy with browser support?

is my current course a solid plan?

or is there a third (fourth, fifth, etc.) option?

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you specifically need the user to edit HTML content (or do complex syntax hilighting etc), go with input/textarea solution. Much cleaner, much more lightweight and easier to do. Contenteditable gets complicated really quickly and using something like tinyMCE or similar would probably be an overkill.

Comment: i wouldn't need anything nearly as powerful as tinyMCE. basically when the user clicks 'edit' button they need to be able to edit text—simply text; no html, no styling, etc.—at which point contenteditable probably wouldn't become too complicated. my current solution *feels* complicated and certainly doesn't seem or feel lightweight.

Comment: There are 3 more pros for the input element. It is supported in mobile browsers, it's visually more recognized as an editable element and you don't have to manually handle user pasted/drag-n-dropped content to strip HTML, which input element does automatically, but contenteditable doesn't. The last one is for UX as you will likely get an unusable contenteditable div/p if the user copies a h1 title into it from somewhere.

Comment: The thing with contenteditable is that it inserts html tags on new line. Different browsers insert different tags (e.g. '<p>', '<br>', '<div>') See the details [here](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-May/031577.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you've used JSfiddle, you know how well contentedible works.  That's what they use.  You can use a jQuery plugin for the syntax highlighting if you need it (Snippet, jquery-syntaxhighlighter).

Comment: i'm not worried about fancier things like highlighting or anything like that. just simple changing of the data. i'll need to investigate contenteditable's compatibility with dumber browsers i suppose :p